# Paths issue after wordpress migration

Tags: wordpress, path, migration

I just moved my wordpress website from a server to another and changed its domain name. I uploaded the files from server 1 and downloaded it to server 2. I also changed the website url in the database (table "wp_options") and changed my DNs and redirection settings (via OVH admin dashboard).
Problem is, the website isn't displaying correctly, a lot of things aren't found on server and all the links redirect to the old domain. Yet I can see a few things on the home page. Also, when i try to go to www.myNewDomain.com/wp-admin I am redirected to www.myOldDomain.com/wp-admin.

Any idea where this could come from and how to fix it?

Comment: It is possible that it didn't change in wp_config.php Check here https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Edit_wp-config.php

Comment: Hi, and thank you for your fast answer. I forgot to mention that, but i made changes in wp_config.php and specified the right database credentials. My home page displays picture and text content but style sheets and scripts cant be found...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your website URLs everywhere in the exported DB file (not just table "wp_options") and while changing the link, be aware to exclude http or www (just use main domain like "stackoverflow.com")

Comment: Thanks Deepak, i'll have a look at that hoping that it fix the issue and will let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that you can use to update your urls in phpmyadmin. Use the SQL tab to run these. This should fix your 404's on your migrated content. Make sure to change the table prefix if it isn't 'wp'.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'http://www.newsiteurl.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'src="http://www.oldsiteurl.com', 'src="http://yourcdn.newsiteurl.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET  guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com', http://yourcdn.newsiteurl.com') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'http://www.oldsiteurl.com','http://www.newsiteurl.com');
```